# .htaccess block all sub posts from category

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Need to block all urls thet under `/category` from htacess.
for example block acces to `mysite.com/category/post`
I have browsed in google but there are nothing about block all after ...
Maby there better solution to block not from htaccess ill happy to know.
Thanks advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/tintogames/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?tintogames\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: anubhava maybe it block acess after `category/...`
but i need to block `mywebsite.com/category/` too
thanks advanced

Comment: This will block `/category` OR `/category/` OR `/category/post`

Comment: Sorry but it doesent. Check out
http://high-tech.co/tintogames/ 
and
http://high-tech.co/tintogames/brrr

Comment: Well I tested it before posting and it worked. Is `/category` a directory?

Comment: yes it is, if you know godaddy hosting doesent allows to create new directory out of first directory so my other websites folders for example tintogames is in high-tech's folder... im confused and dont know how to block access from high-tech.co to tintogames.net's files ...

Comment: Yes im, what can i do there ?

Comment: ok see update to my answer. Add that line in your tintogames/.htaccess file

Comment: anubhava, But now tintogames.net doesent allow access too =(